# UICollectionView and Constraints

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

Has anyone encountered this? I have a UICollectionView dropped in my Storyboard. It has 20 sections and each has a few cells (imagine a calendar where every month is a section which fills the collection view bounds). I am adding constraints and this seems to affect the rendering of the cells. Some cells disappear (some days are not visible) and there is a margin between sections (although no such thing has been set). Any ideas as to why this might be happening?

Comment: This is not enough information to diagnose the problem. What do you mean by "some cells disappear"? Some images might help.

Comment: Are you getting any autolayout warnings in interface builder?

Comment: @rdelmar Sorry for this. I have updated my description. Let's say that on section 15 there are 2 cells that are not displaying.

Comment: What constraints are you adding/ wanting to add?

Comment: Are you using the default flow layout? I don't see any reason adding constraints would affect the collection view the way you say. Obviously, if the constraints change the size of the collection view, that would affect the layout, but it shouldn't make cells disappear.

Comment: I am using a custom layout. The most curious thing is the margins at the sections that are only there when the parent view (the one that contains the collection view) has constraints.

Comment: The only affect that the constraints should have is changing the size of the collection view, so the response you're seeing must have something to do with your custom layout not correctly dealing with this size change.